# How can I create array type from element type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have this:

```
function foo<T>(...items: T[]) {}
foo(1)
```

I would like to get an array type for passed arguments, e.g. 1 is NumericLiteral then I need ts.Type === number[].
Of course I need to handle something like this:

```
let b = ["abacaba"]; foo(...b); foo("a", ...b, "c");
```

The needed type is string[]

How can I implement such type conversion using Typescript Compiler API?